# Is there any tool to convert Simple HTML table to accessible table?

Tags: html, xhtml, accessibility

I don't want to recreat whole table . i need any WYSIWYG/gui/interface online/offline tool to convert already made HTML tables to highly Accessible table as much as possible.

Which IDE/web design software/WYSIWYG Editor/ has best Table editor to make accessible table?

Just for example like this table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Item</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Threaded screws</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Flat nails</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Dyna-bolts</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Spring washers</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Kilo</strong></td>
        <td>$2.50</td>
        <td>$3.50</td>
        <td>$4.50</td>
        <td>$2.50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Pound</strong></td>
        <td>$2.00</td>
        <td>$3.00</td>
        <td>$4.00</td>
        <td>$2.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

to this

```
<table summary="Table of screws, Flat nails, Dyna-bolts and
Spring washers, in kilos and pounds">
    <caption>
        Pricing for screws, Flat nails and Dyna-bolts
    </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th id="screws" abbr="screws">Threaded screws</th>
            <th id="nails" abbr="nails">Flat nails</th>
            <th id="bolts" abbr="bolts">Dyna-bolts</th>
            <th id="washers" abbr="washers">Spring washers</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th id="kilo">Kilo</th>
            <td headers="screws kilo">$2.50</td>
            <td headers="nails kilo">$3.50</td>
            <td headers="bolts kilo">$4.50</td>
            <td headers="washers kilo">$2.50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="pound">Pound</th>
            <td headers="screws pound">$2.00</td>
            <td headers="nails pound">$3.00</td>
            <td headers="bolts pound">$4.00</td>
            <td headers="washers pound">$2.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: See my answer below for full details, but basically you don't need to add id/headers attributes *if the table is a simple table*; they are only needed where th alone can't describe it. This makes your task simpler, so you may no longer need a tool to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, I'd just do this by hand.

If these table are dynamically generated, the code should be straight forward to figure out even with the most minimal of guidance as to what to add and change. Even someone who is not a programmer can make these changes once someone points out the way.

The time to set up and describe the data to a tool would be likely longer and more arduous than simply changing the tables by hand. Cut and paste are your friend here, so is Search/Replace. Use an editor that let's you Search/Replace within a selection.

If you have that, in the example you gave, you can select the first block of rows and change "<td>" to "<td headers="screws kilo">" in a click.

In the end, you have to type this stuff in to something anyway, at least once. Likely the tool will just get in the way.

Answer (score 1):

LIFT extension for Macromedia Dreamweaver 4 from Usabletnet is supposed to provide a wizard to convert simple table into accessible table with ids and headers. It's still on [sale](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000079W4S) but no longer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I've yet to come across such a tool.

Even if there's one, you might spend more time mapping the tags/attributes than actually coding it from scratch.

Or perhaps writing one mapping tool for your own use if you need to convert huge number of tables with similar structure.

Comment: yeah, i can do this manually but i wanted to save some time if possible bcoz i have to convert lots of table. and i don't know programming so i can't write tool for myself

Answer (score 0):

You'd be hard pressed to find a reliable method of doing this with a WYSIWYG editor.

Do it by hand -any editor that allows you to **find/replace** within a **selection** should help to speed up the process. Since your attributes differ from each other you could use it just to insert the attribute names and do the rest yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can do a bit of find and replace but generally this is a task best done by hand. If you were starting a table from scratch the Accessible Table Builder' tool on Accessiby.com might be useful.
http://accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/accessibility-tools/table-builder/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the id/headers attributes here - this looks like a simple table, with just one set of row and column headers. id/headers are only needed with complex tables where a cell may have multiple row/col headers - which is common if you have nested headers - but that's not the case here.

See [WCAG 2.0, note on using id and headers](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H43):

> This technique is used when data cells are associated with more than one row and/or one column header. This allows screen readers to speak the headers associated with each data cell when the relationships are too complex to be identified using the th element alone or the th element with the scope attribute

In your case, however, TH alone is sufficient.

So all you really need to change here is to add a summary - which you need to add manually anyhow since that's not in the original source - and then make the strong TD's into TH's.

And that seems to be doable with a simple search/replace of `<td><strong>` to `<th>` and `</strong></td>` to `</th>`, which any editor should be able to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the example you've given as boilerplate code, and manually cut and paste or Search/Replace rather than attempt to auto-generate a table.

There are [online table generators](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables), but I am not aware of any that generate accessible tables.

Comment: hey @herrenchek just to give you more details to KirillMatrosov 's point... Usually when one downvotes you (and is respectful about it like this case) they would leave a comment to get back to this if you make some changes. Remember that you can always edit your answer after some research.